# SQLite Installation message

Tags: sqlite

While installing SQLite I am getting message as

```
SQLite version 3.9.2 2015-11-02 18:31:45
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite>
```

what it means transient in-memory database?

Comment: Please if you can help me to know next steps to start server for sqlite

Comment: This has nothing to do with installation; you are running the [command-line shell](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html). And SQLite is not a server.

Comment: I want to use sqlite with Django framework on Microsoft visual studio.While syncing django project with db I am not able to see option for sqlite

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) says:

> An SQLite database is normally stored in a single ordinary disk file. However, in certain circumstances, the database might be stored in memory.
>   […]
>   When this is done, no disk file is opened. Instead, a new database is created purely in memory. The database ceases to exist as soon as the database connection is closed.